# Menu unserialized warning when using autocomplete in a custom module

Tags: 7, routes

I am working on creating a form with Autocomplete feature for the text field. This is the code I have so far..

```
    /**
     * Implementation of hook_menu()
     */
    function suggest_feature_menu() {  
      $item['suggest_feature/autocomplete'] = array(   
        'page callback' => '_suggest_feature_autocomplete',   
        'access arguments' => user_access('access example autocomplete'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
        ); 

        return $item;
      }

    /**
     * Implementation of autocomplete
     */

 function suggest_feature_autocomplete($string){

    $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
    ->condition('status', 1) //Published.
    ->condition('type', array('e_hood', 'oranization'))
    ->condition('n.title','%'.db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC') //Most recent first.
    ->range(0,10)
    ->execute();

    $items = array();

    foreach ($query as $node){
       $items[$node->nid] = check_plain($node->title);
    }

    return drupal_json_output($items);

  }

    /**
     * Implementation of hook_form()
     */


    function suggest_feature_form($form_state) {
     $form = array();

       $form['test_item'] = array(   
        '#type' => 'textfield',   
        '#autocomplete_path' => 'suggest_feature/autocomplete'  
        ); 

      return $form;
    }
```

all my functionality works but i get a warning which says

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in menu_unserialize()
>   (line 393 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\includes\menu.inc).

Please let me know how to solve this. Is this an issue with my code ? Also I use superfish menu's in my drupal. Is this related ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but the `'title'` property is required for items defined in [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), and it's missing in your code.

I can think of a couple of scenarios where a lack of the `'title'` property might cause this error in `menu_unserialize()` so it's worth adding it to see if that helps. Remember to flush the caches once you make the code change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't work..

Comment: Also do you know how to filter autocomplete results based on type ?

Answer (score 2):

There are three functions calling [`menu_unserialize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_unserialize/7.x), the function for which the error is reported:

- [`menu_get_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7.x) uses it in the following code

  ```
    if ($router_item['access']) {
      $router_item['map'] = $map;
      $router_item['page_arguments'] = array_merge(menu_unserialize($router_item['page_arguments'], $map), array_slice($map, $router_item['number_parts']));
      $router_item['theme_arguments'] = array_merge(menu_unserialize($router_item['theme_arguments'], $map), array_slice($map, $router_item['number_parts']));
    }
  ```
- [`_menu_check_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/_menu_check_access/7.x) uses it in the following code

  ```
  $arguments = menu_unserialize($item['access_arguments'], $map);
  ```
- _menu_item_localize() uses it in the following code

  ```
  $item['title'] = t($item['title'], menu_unserialize($item['title_arguments'], $map));
  ```

The *Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`* error simply means that `foreach()` is getting a value that is not an array. With the code you are showing, that is happening only for `$arguments = menu_unserialize($item['access_arguments'], $map);` since you are setting `$item['suggest_feature/autocomplete']['access arguments']` to `TRUE` when it should be an array.

In your case, the code should be the following one.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function suggest_feature_menu() {  
  $item['suggest_feature/autocomplete'] = array(   
    'page callback' => '_suggest_feature_autocomplete',   
    'access arguments' => array('access example autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  ); 

  return $item;
}
```

For Drupal that code would be equivalent to the following one.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function suggest_feature_menu() {  
  $item['suggest_feature/autocomplete'] = array(   
    'page callback' => '_suggest_feature_autocomplete',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access example autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  ); 

  return $item;
}
```

You can understand now why your code is wrong.

It's not the access arguments that you can set to a boolean value, but the access callback. See what the documentation for [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) says. (Emphasis is mine.)

> - "access callback": A function returning `TRUE` if the user has access rights to this menu item, and FALSE if not. **It can also be a boolean constant instead of a function, and you can also use numeric values (will be cast to boolean).** Defaults to `user_access()` unless a value is inherited from the parent menu item; only `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` items can inherit access callbacks. To use the `user_access()` default callback, you must specify the permission to check as 'access arguments' (see below).

And for the access arguments, it says:

> - "access arguments": **An array of arguments** to pass to the access callback function, with path component substitution as described above. If the access callback is inherited (see above), the access arguments will be inherited with it, unless overridden in the child menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Your "access argument" in hook_menu must be an array e.g "access argument" => array() in your custom module.